# how do i verify presence of special characters in a bash password generator

Tags: bash, random, passwords, grep, tr

Supposed to be a simple bash script, but turned into a monster.  This is the 5th try.  You don't even want to see the 30 line monstrosity that was attempt #4..  :)

Here's what I want to do:  Script generates a random password, with $1=password length, and $2=amount of special characters present in the output.

Or at least, verify before sending to standard out, that at least 1 special character exists.  I would prefer the former, but settle for the latter.

Here's my very simple 5th version of this script.  It has no verification, or $2:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc [=!=][=@=][=#=][=$=][=%=][=^=][:alnum:] | head -c $1
```

This works just fine, and it's a sufficiently secure password with Usage:

```
$ passgen 12
2ZuQacN9M@6!
```

But it, of course, doesn't always print special characters, and it's become an obsession for me now to be able to allow selection of how many special characters are present in the output.  It's not as easy as I thought.

Make sense?

By the way, I don't mind a complete rework of the code, I'd be very interested to see some creative solutions!

(By the way:  I've tried to pipe it into egrep/grep in various ways, to no avail, but I have a feeling that is a possible solution...)

Thanks
Kevin

Comment: for the love of god....use a real programming language for programming tasks.

Comment: well the original goal, before this turned into a monster, was to write it in bash, then write it in ruby, run each script 100 times, and average the time it takes to run each and compare.  I like real programming languages, but i like the challenge of bash

Comment: also, sometimes bash is the best for the job.  it's fast and dirty, and reliable, that is - if you know what you're doing, which i clearly don't :)

Comment: i actually wish i could downgrade the @Kim Stebel comment.  It's like if someone says, Hey how do I replace transmission on an 82 ford mustang, and someone says, "BUY A NEW CAR, DUMBASS"  Yes very helpful, thanks

Comment: except that using a different programming language doesn't cost money and saves a lot of time

Comment: i dont mean to sound hostile, i'm just trying to make a point, i actually do want to learn how to do this in bash

Answer (score 0):

Checking for special characters is easy:

```
echo "$pass" | grep -q '[^a-zA-Z0-9]'
```

Like this:

```
while [ 1 ]; do
    pass=`cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc [=!=][=@=][=#=][=$=][=%=][=^=][:alnum:] | head -c $1`
    if echo "$pass" | grep -q '[^a-zA-Z0-9]'; then
        break;
    fi
done
```

And finally:

```
normal=$(($1 - $2))
(
for ((i=1; i <= $normal; i++)); do
    cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc [:alnum:] | head -c 1
    echo
done
for ((i=1; i <= $2; i++)); do
    cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc [=!=][=@=][=#=][=$=][=%=][=^=] | head -c 1
    echo
done
) | shuf | sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\n//;ta'
```

Comment: i like where you're going with this, but that doesn't work.  I'm looking to verify the existence of special characters, of at least 1.  This doesn't do that?  (I didn't mark your answer down a point by the way)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
HASRANDOM=0
while [ $HASRANDOM -eq 0 ]; do
    PASS=`cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc [=!=][=@=][=#=][=$=][=%=][=^=][:alnum:] | head -c $1`
    if [[ "$PASS" =~ "[~\!@\#\$%^&\*\(\)\-\+\{\}\\\/=]{$2,}" ]]; then
        HASRANDOM=1
    fi  
done

echo $PASS
```

Supports specifying characters in the output. You could add characters in the regex though I couldn't seem to get square brackets to work even when escaping them.

You probably would want to add some kind of check to make sure it doesn't loop infinitely (though it never went that far for me but I didn't ask for too many special characters either)

Comment: this is really clever, but it doesn't actually solve the problem fully.

Comment: Oh I see. You want exactly $2 special characters?

Comment: if i run this like:
$ passgen_cfreak 12 2
XL0WEKGVPZP@
YPeW$HsB8Avj
Ap2aSw64NcJW

Comment: Yeah my bad. I forgot to take out the echo I was using to debug. I fixed it. If you want exactly $2 special characters take out the comma after $2

Comment: damn comments... the output is the strings after "passgen_cfreak 12 2"

do you see how the 3rd one does not contain special characters?

Comment: Check now. I had left an extra echo in that should have been removed. It should now just echo once and it should certainly contain at least the number of special characters requested.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple... Solution in awk that return the number of "special characters" in input

```
BEGIN {
    FS=""
    split("!@#$%^",special,"")
}
{
    split($0,array,"")
}
END {
    for (i in array) {
        for (s in special) {
            if (special[s] == array[i])
                tot=tot+1
        }
    }
    print tot
}
```

Example output for `a2ZuQacN9M@6!` is

```
2
```

Similar approach in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
MyString=a2ZuQacN9M@6!
special=!@#$%^

i=0
while (( i++ < ${#MyString} ))
do
   char=$(expr substr "$MyString" $i 1)
   n=0
    while (( n++ < ${#special} ))
    do
       s=$(expr substr "$special" $n 1)
       if [[ $s == $char ]]
       then
           echo $s
       fi
    done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use a character class in parameter expansion to delete all special chars in a string and then apply some simple Bash string length math to check if there was a minimum (or exact) number of special chars in the password.

```
# example: delete all punctuation characters in string
str='a!@%3"'
echo "${str//[[:punct:]]/}"   

# ... taking Cfreak's approach we could write ...
(
set -- 12 3
strlen1=$1
strlen2=0
nchars=$2
special_chars='[=!=][=@=][=#=][=$=][=%=][=^=]'  

HASRANDOM=0
while [ $HASRANDOM -eq 0 ]; do
  PASS=`cat /dev/urandom | LC_ALL=C tr -dc "${special_chars}[:alnum:]" | head -c $1`
  PASS2="${PASS//[${special_chars}]/}"
  strlen2=${#PASS2}
  #if [[ $((strlen1 - strlen2)) -eq $nchars ]]; then   # set exact number of special chars
  if [[ $((strlen1 - strlen2)) -ge $nchars ]]; then   # set minimum number of special chars
    echo "$PASS"
    HASRANDOM=1
  fi
done
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of special chars using something like:

```
number of characters - number of non special characters
```

Try this:

```
$ # define a string
$ string='abc!d$'                    
$ # extract non special chars to letters
$ letters=$(echo $string | tr -dc [:alnum:] )  
$ # substract the number on non special chars from total
$ echo $(( ${#string} - ${#letters} ))         
2
```

The last part `$(( ... ))` evaluate a mathematical expression.